# Underwater Seasonal Ice?

Tags: science-based, planets, climate, seasons

I'm attempting to create a planet that's 90% covered in water (as in 10% of the land is above the surface, not mass or volume). However, I want some large-scale event to occur every year or so that reduces the global water level.

My idea involves a large, sub-surface glacier that melts every summer. I'm assuming that the global water level would drop as ice is less dense than water. The significant issues I see are the amount of salt in the ocean, the internal heat, and heat from the sun.

Also, due to the nature of the planet, I'm thinking about using a highly eccentric orbit to shorten the summer and increase the winter. Whether or not that helps, I do not know.

Thanks in advance, I'm excited to hear your answers!

Comment: There's also the small issue that ice _is_ less dense than water; so how is it sub-surface?

Comment: Also, ice is freshwater that crystallises out from saltwater in the seas on Earth. This makes it even more buoyant as the saltwater it's floating on is denser than freshwater. Double whammy.

Comment: I... probably should have thought of that lol. Alright, two ideas come to mind: First, what about a liquid denser than water? It may be tough to find a working substance with a solid form less dense than its liquid form, but I'll look into it.

Second, what if the ice froze when the water was lower and only partially melts? Would the temperature of the remaining ice be enough to re-freeze the water every winter?

Comment: I don't know nearly enough physics to make this an answer, but maybe a seasonal change in how much water is evaporated? i.e., at perihelion temperatures are significantly higher and more water is contained in the atmosphere as vapor, at aphelion it's cooler and that water is back in the ocean.

Comment: How much reduction are we looking for? Cutting it by 50% isn't going to happen without magic. Does it matter if the global *volume* is reduced? or is it enough that the amount of landmass that's exposed is increased? Please be very specific and detailed about what it means to "[reduce] the global water level."

Comment: Another question. Does most of the land (by surface area) have to be habitable? You could hypothetically create large seasonal ice caps at the poles by letting them 'seed' off land masses at the poles as they do on Earth off Antarctica or Greenland etc but that also means most of your land will be largely uninhabitable.

Comment: JBH, by 'reduce the global water level' I mean increase the amount of land mass exposed.

Comment: Mon, I would prefer if most of the land is habitable, although I'll take your idea into consideration. It's certainly a good back up

Comment: @Onennon OK, by how much? Is an inch enough?

Comment: @Onennon I'm not being facetious. Giving your planet a moon will expose dozens of feet of land on each orbit of the moon. Slow the moon's rotation and your problem is solved... unless what you want is to expose miles of your landmass (might be back to magic on that one). You'll also need to define the landmass. Is it a steep mountain? A simple hill on what's otherwise a plateau? Please be ***specific and detailed.*** (See [help/on-topic].)

Comment: Excuse me, I haven't given specifics too much thought as I wanted to know if it was even possible first. I suppose anything over a hundred feet vertically is fine. As for what a landmass is, it's an entire planet, so any form of land from mountain to molehill. If all it takes is a slow-orbiting moon then I'll go with that.

Comment: Real-world parallel: the lakes of Titan probably do exactly this, except we're talking about liquid methane and methane ice instead of water.

Comment: Thinking about the moon idea again, I'm not sure if it would work on an annual scale. Assuming the moon orbited at the same speed the planet rotates, one side of the planet will always have high tides. If the moon orbits at the same speed the planet orbits, the planet's rotation with cause the tides to move around the globe like normal tides.

Comment: @biziclop That's an interesting point! And looking up the densities of methane also said that ice (of both methane and water) may not float to the top of their respective liquids if they're "bound in place by being formed in or anchored to sediment." I'm hoping we can return to the idea that the undersea ice doesn't entirely melt every year, giving a basis for new ice to form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified what exactly would be acceptable, but if the planet was close to being tidally locked to its parent star an annual tide might be possible.

I doubt that a moon would be able to produce a large enough effect or remain in stable orbit to produce such an effect.

Comment: Thats a good idea but I feel like a planet being tidally locked would create its own issues regarding temperature and livability. Also, I think I'm looking for something other than a true tide (like those caused by the moon). I'm looking for a global change in the water level, similar to climate change.

Comment: Fair enough, but you need to make all that clear in the question (welcome to world building BTW). I don't think it would be possible to  do what you want specifically. The main problem being any change in phase (liquid to solid) would require too great an energy input over too short a period. It would be like melting and freezing the whole of Antarctica every year.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. Just as I thought I had something, too! You know, my world actually has magic so I could have come up with some fantasy reason this whole time. Despite magic being quite rare I suppose I'll have to fall back on it in this case. Your phrasing, "melting and freezing the whole of Antarctica," really put into perspective the scale of what I'm trying to do. Thank you very much for your help, and I'm happy to say I felt I've learned a lot. That goes for any of the previous commenters as well, you've all been a great help!

Comment: No Problem. You can see how important it is to get the setting of the question right. You need your world to be human habitable (I imagine). But does the whole planet need to have a sea level increase? One word of warning about magic, use it if you wish but I would suggest keeping it consistent and restrict its uses (perhaps it requires a lot of karma or something).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Luckily I'm already planning on restricting the ability to use magic in humans. I don't know how specifically but I want magic to be something that doesn't rely on luck, so I'll probably just have people learn it. It's also supposed to be very rare so I'll try and find ways to make magic have a huge drawback or something.

As for the magic that causes the ocean to rise and fall, I think I'll just have a giant sea monster at the bottom of the ocean. The project is supposed to be Lovecraftian so it won't be out of place.